# WCF Service Reference using XmlSerializer creating Temp Dynamic Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, memory-leaks, .net-assembly

I have been trying to diagnose what I think is a well documented memory leak where an executable's memory increases in size due to a WCF Service Reference (or old style web reference too) due to it creating dynamic temp assemblies on the fly by an XmlSerializer

I have found a previous stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359367/wcf-message-serialization-leaking-event-handles-and-unmanaged-memory) which also provides [this link](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/wcf-memory-leak-with.html) which describes the issue in some detail.

What it doesnt do is provide any idea on how to cache the XmlSerializer / MessageTypeConverter in order to prevent these dynamic assemblies from being created.

So my question is - how do I prevent the XmlSerializer from generating dynamic assemblies when the serialization occurs in the depths of the WCF/.NET infrastructure layer?

For interest, here is the full stack trace from the assemblies (as provided by ANTS memory profiler:

```
System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(string name)
System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerator.CreateModuleBuilder(Emit.AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder, string name)
System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateRefEmitAssembly(Serialization.XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, string defaultNamespace, Policy.Evidence evidence)
System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(Serialization.XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, string defaultNamespace, string location, Policy.Evidence evidence)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(Serialization.XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, string defaultNamespace, string location, Policy.Evidence evidence)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Type[] extraTypes, Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, string defaultNamespace, string location, Policy.Evidence evidence)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Type[] extraTypes, Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, string defaultNamespace, string location)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root)
```

EDIT: I should also mention, I am aware of this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751883(v=vs.110).aspx), however even with this, my executables memory increases (with the profile above), so it looks like for whatever reason that the MyLIbrary.XmlSerializers.dll is not being used, or is being used, but not cached.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was an explicit call to instantiate a new XmlSerializer in our code using the attributeroot constructor overload. Correcting this fixed our issue.

We also managed to find a way to manually override the XmlSerializer being used in wcf creating a operation behavior.